# Use of non-ascii credentials not working in httpclient 4.3.x

Tags: java, character-encoding, apache-httpclient-4.x

I looked up the httpclient 4.3.3 APIs on how to specify the charset to be used for headers so the Authorization header containing the username/password can use a specific charset such as UTF-8 or iso-8859-1. The deprecated 3.x API used for this is

```
httpMethodInstance.getParams().setHttpElementCharset("iso-8859-1");
```

The equivalent API in 4.3.3, I found is in ConnectionConfig. Following is the code I tried using

```
HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));

builder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);

ConnectionConfig connectionConfig = ConnectionConfig.custom()
        .setCharset(Charset.forName("iso-8859-1")).build();
BasicHttpClientConnectionManager connManager = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager(
        registryBuilder.build());
connManager.setConnectionConfig(connectionConfig);
builder.setConnectionManager(connManager);



HttpHost target = new HttpHost(host, port, scheme);
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
localContext.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

CloseableHttpClient httpclient = builder.build();
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, request, localContext);
```

But the base64 encoded value of the credentials sent across in the authorization header indicates that the credentials are not encoded using the specified charset "iso-8859-1". Is ConnectionConfig.setCharset() the right method to use to set the http header charset? If not, what is the correct equivalent of the deprecated setHttpElementCharset() in 4.3.x?

Apache mail archive http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hc-dev/201407.mbox/%3CJIRA.12727350.1405435834469.45355.1405437005945@arcas%3E indicates this is not readily supported and suggests the use of BasicSchemeFactory but I can't seem to figure out how/where to specify the charset using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom charset encoding is applicable to some auth schemes (such Basic and Digest) and not applicable to others. Global custom auth charset parameter was a bad idea

Credentials charset has to be configured on a per scheme basis using custom auth scheme factories

```
Lookup<AuthSchemeProvider> authSchemeRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<AuthSchemeProvider>create()
            .register(AuthSchemes.BASIC, new BasicSchemeFactory(Consts.UTF_8))
            .register(AuthSchemes.DIGEST, new DigestSchemeFactory(Consts.UTF_8))
            .register(AuthSchemes.NTLM, new NTLMSchemeFactory())
            .register(AuthSchemes.SPNEGO, new SPNegoSchemeFactory())
            .register(AuthSchemes.KERBEROS, new KerberosSchemeFactory())
            .build();
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultAuthSchemeRegistry(authSchemeRegistry)
        .build();
```